# Citations in order of appearance

Tags: biblatex, natbib

I am currently writing my thesis and using the class file provided by my university. Everything is fine and compiles well except for the citations and references.

The default setting is order the references alphabetically, but I want them ordered numerically....that is in the order in which I cited the references.

I have tried using

```
\usepackage[super,sort&compress]{natbib}
```

and then

```
\begin{document}
\bibliographystyle{unsrtnat}
\bibfiles{chap1,chap2,chap3,chap4,chap5}
\bibpunct{[}{]}{,}{s}{}{}
```

It does not work....I can see it modifying my references in some way. The first citation is [1] and then [2], but the third citation is [39]!

I also tried `biblatex`.

```
\pdfoptionpdfminorversion=6
\documentclass[12pt,hyperref]{gatech-thesis}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,latexsym,float,epsfig,subfigure,textcomp}
\usepackage[style=numeric-comp]{biblatex}
\bibliography{chap1,chap2,chap3,chap4,chap5,chap6}
\usepackage[]{hyperref}

\begin{document}
\printbibliography
```

This one gives me a Latex error "Can only be used in preamble"....I tried reordering the location of the `\usepackage[style=numeric-comp]{biblatex`} command, but I still cannot get it to work.

But I did notice that a test file that I created to check `biblatex` (below) runs perfectly without any issues.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[style=numeric-comp]{biblatex}
\bibliography{examples}
\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

So, I am not sure I understand why it won't work with the original class file. I would appreciate your help.

I think this is further complicated by the fact that I have citations within Figure captions.

`\caption{blah blah...\cite{xyz}}`

This might also be responsible for the problem.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) A tip: If you indent lines by 4 spaces, they'll be [marked as a code sample](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1192/how-do-i-mark-code-blocks). You can also highlight the code and click the "code" button (with "{}" on it). There's also no need to 'sign' your post: your name is automatically added.

Comment: Thanks Joseph, I am new to this forum so thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: The `gatech-thesis` class redefines the bibliography commands and is therefore not compatible with `biblatex` without a good amount of modification.  When you used `natbib`, did you make sure to run latex at least twice after running bibtex?

Comment: @Alan: As my MWE seems to work, could you give some details with regard to the imcompatibility?

Comment: Alan..I don't run Bibtex separately. I run Latex to PDF....in fact my editor (TexNiccenter) has the "run Bibtex" option grayed out.....sorry but I only have a basic knowledge of latex..

Comment: lockstep....your MWE works....but how would I go about incorporating all the references in my bibfiles in your working example? is there a simple way to do it? thanks!

Comment: @Avi: You need to run `bibtex` in order to process the references before they can be included. The first run of two, as Alan suggests, saves information that LaTeX will use on a second run. However, inbetween these runs you need to run `bibtex`. You should be able to do so from the command line, or activate this in TeXnicCenter by *unchecking* the appropriate box.

Comment: @lockstep Well minimally, the entries aren't single spaced with a blank line between them. Also, the standard `biblatex` style doesn't quite match that basic `natbib` style (idiosyncrasies such as using "In:" for journals, e.g. ) I'm not saying these aren't solvable, but depending on what the thesis requirements are, it may be better to stick with the `natbib` solution.

Comment: actually I just found out that my latex to pdf sequence includes the bibtex and makeindex options....so looks like I am doing everything in one sequence. I am compiling multiple times though....but I ran just bibtex after running latex once and I am getting 6 errors (which do not show up when I run the latex to pdf with bibtex and makeindex all together) that seem syntax related....is that why the references won't line up numerically?

Comment: Give us a complete example that produces the error.

Comment: my bad....I confirmed again...no errors when running Bibtex...only warnings...no light at the end of the tunnel. My first reference is the thesis is [7].....do you think the class file is so sucky that it won't let natbib control the references?

Answer (score 8):

The following minimal example compiles correctly and produces the right reference number ordering. (Numbers begin at 1 and bibliography is in citation order rather than alphabetical.)  If this works properly for you, then there is some other interaction with your document which will need some detective work to find out. If you have switched between `biblatex` and `natbib` in the course of figuring this out, make sure you delete *all* auxiliary files associated to your thesis and then try again.

```
\documentclass[hyperref]{gatech-thesis}
\usepackage[super,sort&compress]{natbib}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@incollection{Baauw2001,
    Address = {Somerville, MA},
    Author = {Sergio Baauw},
    Booktitle = {Proceedings of the 25th Annual Boston University Conference on Language Development},
    Editor = {A. H.-J. Do and L. Dom{\'\i}nguez and A. Johansen},
    Pages = {82-93},
    Publisher = {Cascadilla Press},
    Title = {Expletive determiners in child Dutch and Spanish},
    Year = {2001}}

@article{barker1998,
    Author = {Chris Barker},
    Journal = {Natural Language \& Linguistic Theory},
    Pages = {679-717},
    Title = {Partitives, Double Genitives and Anti-Uniqueness},
    Volume = {16},
    Year = {1998}}

@book{Berwick1985,
    Address = {Cambridge, MA},
    Author = {Berwick, Robert C.},
    Publisher = {MIT Press},
    Title = {Acquisition of syntactic knowledge},
    Year = {1985}}

@phdthesis{Carlson1977,
    Author = {Carlson, Gregory N.},
    School = {University of Massachusetts, Amherst},
    Title = {Reference to Kinds in {E}nglish},
    Year = {1977}}

\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}
\bibpunct{[}{]}{,}{s}{}{} 
\bibfiles{\jobname}


\bibliographystyle{unsrtnat}

\chapter{A chapter}
Some text.\cite{Carlson1977} Some text  \cite{Berwick1985} Some text \cite{Barker1998,Baauw2001}
\references
\end{document}
```

The `gatech-thesis` class is not designed to work with `biblatex`, and redefines the `bibliography` command to conform with the formatting requirements of your school. Although it might be possible to make it work with `biblatex` it would require quite a bit of modification.

Comment: Alan....thanks a ton. Your MWE seems to be working for me. But there might be a bug either in my references or some clash between the class file and natbib, because when I include ALL citations, it reverts back to the crazy ordering.However, currently I have commented out a large chunk of my thesis such that there are only 5 citations and that works like a charm...will give you an update soon. Also....is there a way I can input the references instead of having them all like above? It will clutter my file since I have more than 200 references. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Avi We only put references like this here on the site so that examples are self-contained. (The filecontents package just writes out its contents to a file.)  So you would just have your references in your own bib file managed with e.g. JabRef (or BibDesk if you're using a Mac).  You don't actually need a separate file for each chapter; you could just have one big file.

Comment: I think I can see what is going on.....I have citations (using \cite) within Figure captions. And this is what is screwing things up. So, for some reason the citations in the figure captions are automatically prioritized and bumped up to the top of the list and that in turn screws everything.

Comment: I don't think there's an easy way around this. It's probably best to avoid such references when you are using a citation order scheme.

Comment: Well...I can't avoid the citations since I am referring to someone else's scientific work. I had already tried \protect to no avail....lets see...worst case I would have to remove the citation..but I am getting close to a solution. I think my original file was fine...the problem I feel was always the citations in the figure captions

Comment: Another possibility would be to not have those particular figures float (i.e. don't enclose them in a `{figure}` environment), and then use the `\captionof` command of the `caption` package to place the caption.

Answer (score 2):

@Alan ...MOUNT EVEREST SCALED!!! The following solves all:

[LaTeX Citations in Figures](http://www.terminally-incoherent.com/blog/2006/07/26/latex-citations-in-figures/) works very well.

```
\caption[Carrier mobilities of various forms of silicon. From Rogers et.al.]
        {Carrier mobilities of various forms of silicon. From Rogers et.al.
        \protect\cite{rogers:paper}
```

instead of

```
\caption{Carrier mobilities of various forms of silicon. From Rogers et.al. 
     \protect\cite{rogers:paper}
```

i have tried this with 10 citations and it works...citations appear in numerical order.

Wow....I don't need to defend my PhD anymore...this feels like a defense in itself! Thanks a TON guys. You are going into my acknowledgements (@Alan with a special mention!:))

Comment: @Avi I'm glad you found a solution (I had forgotten about the list of figures problem). But I think you've just gotten lucky so far.  With a citation order scheme, it's still possible to have citations in floats appear in the wrong order independent of the solution you post here.  Hopefully you won't encounter this.

Comment: BTW, It would be helpful if you edited your original question to show the actual problem you had, so that this answer matches it properly.

Comment: So Alan....what is the best solution? Not to use citations in Figure captions at all?

Comment: updated problem statement to include the issue with citations within captions

Comment: @Avi I don't know. I don't use this citation scheme generally. I've asked a new question to see if anyone here has some other ideas. [Unsorted citations and floats](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/31696/unsorted-citations-and-floats)

Comment: @Alan......yups. Hope someone clarifies that issue and comes up with a more elegant solution than what I found out