# Unsorted citations and floats

Tags: floats, bibliographies, citing, sorting

In attempting to answer this question [Citations in order of appearance](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/31663/citations-in-order-of-appearance) it's clear that  unsorted citation schemes (ones in which the citations are numbered simply by order of appearance) can be easily messed up with floats.  Here is a minimal example exhibiting the problem.

```
\documentclass[12pt,oneside]{book}
\usepackage[super,sort&compress]{natbib}
\bibpunct{[}{]}{,}{s}{}{} 
\bibliographystyle{unsrtnat}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{caption}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@incollection{Baauw2001,
    Address = {Somerville, MA},
    Author = {Sergio Baauw},
    Booktitle = {Proceedings of the 25th Annual Boston University Conference on Language Development},
    Editor = {A. H.-J. Do and L. Dom{\'\i}nguez and A. Johansen},
    Pages = {82-93},
    Publisher = {Cascadilla Press},
    Title = {Expletive determiners in child Dutch and Spanish},
    Year = {2001}}

@article{barker1998,
    Author = {Chris Barker},
    Journal = {Natural Language \& Linguistic Theory},
    Pages = {679-717},
    Title = {Partitives, Double Genitives and Anti-Uniqueness},
    Volume = {16},
    Year = {1998}}

@book{Berwick1985,
    Address = {Cambridge, MA},
    Author = {Berwick, Robert C.},
    Publisher = {MIT Press},
    Title = {Acquisition of syntactic knowledge},
    Year = {1985}}

@phdthesis{Carlson1977,
    Author = {Carlson, Gregory N.},
    School = {University of Massachusetts, Amherst},
    Title = {Reference to Kinds in {E}nglish},
    Year = {1977}}

\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}

\chapter{A chapter}
\lipsum
Some text.\cite{Carlson1977}
\lipsum[3]
\cite{Barker1998,Baauw2001}
\begin{figure}[tbp]
\centering
\includegraphics[width=.5\textwidth]{demo.jpg}
\captionof{figure}[A figure from Berwick]{A figure from \protect\cite{Berwick1985}}
\end{figure}
\lipsum[2]
\bibliography{\jobname}
\end{document}
```

[image: partial output of code]

Because the citation in the figure is the fourth cited in the document source, it appears with number [4].  However, because the figure has floated to the top of the page, the number now appears out of order.  I don't use this citation style, but I'm wondering if there is any way around it short of the following two (non-)solutions:

1. Avoid using citations in captions altogether.
2. Avoid using floats for figures that have citations and use the `\captionof` command of the `caption` package (or similar methods) to add the caption.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I tried the following which seems to work in the MWE. I don't know what will happen in an other document.

```
\documentclass[12pt,oneside]{book}
\usepackage[super,sort&compress]{natbib}
\bibpunct{[}{]}{,}{s}{}{} 
\bibliographystyle{unsrtnat}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{caption}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@incollection{Baauw2001,
    Address = {Somerville, MA},
    Author = {Sergio Baauw},
    Booktitle = {Proceedings of the 25th Annual Boston University Conference on Language Development},
    Editor = {A. H.-J. Do and L. Dom{\'\i}nguez and A. Johansen},
    Pages = {82-93},
    Publisher = {Cascadilla Press},
    Title = {Expletive determiners in child Dutch and Spanish},
    Year = {2001}}

@article{barker1998,
    Author = {Chris Barker},
    Journal = {Natural Language \& Linguistic Theory},
    Pages = {679-717},
    Title = {Partitives, Double Genitives and Anti-Uniqueness},
    Volume = {16},
    Year = {1998}}

@book{Berwick1985,
    Address = {Cambridge, MA},
    Author = {Berwick, Robert C.},
    Publisher = {MIT Press},
    Title = {Acquisition of syntactic knowledge},
    Year = {1985}}

@phdthesis{Carlson1977,
    Author = {Carlson, Gregory N.},
    School = {University of Massachusetts, Amherst},
    Title = {Reference to Kinds in {E}nglish},
    Year = {1977}}

\end{filecontents}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\NAT@sort@cites[1]{%
  \let\NAT@cite@list\@empty
  \@for\@citeb:=#1\do{\expandafter\NAT@star@cite\@citeb\@@}%
  \if@filesw
    \expandafter\write\expandafter\@auxout
      \expandafter{\expandafter\string\expandafter\citation\expandafter{\NAT@cite@list}}%
  \fi
  \@ifnum{\NAT@sort>\z@}{%
    \expandafter\NAT@sort@cites@\expandafter{\NAT@cite@list}%
  }{}%
}%
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\listoffigures
\chapter{A chapter}
\lipsum
Some text.\cite{Carlson1977}
\lipsum[3]
\cite{Barker1998,Baauw2001}
\begin{figure}[tbp]
\centering
\includegraphics[width=.5\textwidth]{demo.jpg}
\caption[A figure from]{A figure from \cite{Berwick1985}}
\end{figure}
\lipsum[2]
\bibliography{\jobname}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Very nice.  That seems to work quite well. I messed around with different placements of the float and it seems to work properly.

Comment: There's additional space before the citation superscript in the caption.

Comment: @lockstep: Thanks. I didn't saw it. But now I have no idea.