# Wrong order of citations in floats (without list of figures)

Tags: biblatex, floats, citing, sorting

I have a problem with the sorting of my citations when using an unsorted citation style within a floating envireonment (e.g. a caption). I found a similar question [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/413040/incorrect-sorting-of-citations-when-captions-are-used-even-without-a-list-of-fi), but the possible solutions don't really work for me.

In the following MWE the problem becomes very clear: The third reference is added in the the image caption, which appears last in the document. In my opinion it should there be cited as "[3]". But (I guess) since it is set first in the source code, LaTeX thinks its the first reference and labels it as "[1]". Is there any sensible solution to this?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{references.bib}
    @article{ref1,
        author = {Smith}
    }
    @article{ref2,
        author = {Jones}
    }
    @article{ref3,
        author = {Williams}
    }
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage[backend=biber, style=nature]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{references.bib}

\begin{document}
    
\begin{figure}[!b]
    \includegraphics{example-image-a}
    \caption{This reference \cite{ref3} appears last and should therefore be labeled as number 3.}
\end{figure}

\lipsum[1]. This is the first reference \cite{ref1}.

\lipsum[2]. This is the second reference \cite{ref2}.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Is this post https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/413040/incorrect-sorting-of-citations-when-captions-are-used-even-without-a-list-of-fi#:~:text=The%20citations%20are%20numbered%20in%20the%20order%20they,not%20want%20floats%20ever%20to%20float%20backwards%20add will help

Comment: That is the exact post I linked in my question. As I stated, that post also doesn't provide a real solution.

Comment: sorry, I didn't see the link in your question.